# Graphhopper returns "not found"

Tags: graphhopper

I'm testing graphhopper for some days now but there is a strange problem
when a Location ist to far away for the next street graphhopper returns the error "not found"
the strange thing is that it works on the graphhopper-demo-server
I tried with alps, europe and now with the whole planet - the error keeps the same

so here it works: https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=47.50562070,14.10270890&point=47.80000740,13.04219230&locale=de&layer=Lyrk

but not on my server: http://osm.testerl.webseiten.cc:8989/?point=47.50562070,14.10270890&point=47.80000740,13.04219230&locale=de&layer=Lyrk

is there a problem with my configuration? I played with index.highResolution ad index.maxRegionSearch but also without a change

other routes are working great

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to play with the settings "prepare.minOnewayNetworkSize=200" or decrease "prepare.minNetworkSize", this way the router does not get stuck in an (oneway) island.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer as solution if it was one for you :) ?