# Different routing behavior between local installation and online service

Tags: graphhopper

I'm trying to use the standalone version of Graphhooper (0.4) to project a route containing a address and a Geo-coordinate in Lat/Long.

While the online example works as expected and is able to project a route for a car. My local installation is not able to calculate a route between the same points. I'm only able to see two points (start & end) on the map but no direction or route appears.

**For Example:**

*Works:*

```
 https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=Munich&point=48.1279%2C11.8129&locale=en-US&layer=Lyrk
```

*Does not work:*

```
http://localhost:8989/?point=Munich&point=48.1279%2C11.8129&locale=en_US&layer=Lyrk
```

**Setup & Config**

The local setup is using **oberbayern-latest.osm.pbf** map data downloaded from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bayern/oberbayern.html)

And the config.properties file has the following settings:

```
graph.dataaccess=RAM_STORE
prepare.minOnewayNetworkSize=200 
prepare.minNetworkSize=100
graph.flagEncoders=car,foot,bike
```

I noticed that the route for *foot* and *bike* can be calculated on my local box and they look the same like the one generated by Graphhopper-API.

*Server startup:*

I started the server with:

```
java -jar *.jar jetty.resourcebase=webapp config=config-example.properties osmreader.osm=oberbayern-latest.osm.pbf
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the other [route not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28455327/194609) questions. Currently the minXY settings you specified are not working for more than one vehicle.