# Graphhopper Connection between locations not found

Tags: java, distance, runtimeexception, graphhopper

I create a graphHopper instance using:

```
 GraphHopper hopper = new GraphHopper().forServer();
 hopper.setCHEnable(false);
 hopper.setGraphHopperLocation("hopper");
 hopper.setOSMFile("greater-london-latest.osm");
 hopper.setEncodingManager(new EncodingManager("car"));
 hopper.setMinNetworkSize(200, 100);
 hopper.importOrLoad();
```

I send a request using:

```
 GHRequest req = new GHRequest().addPoint(new GHPoint(latFrom, lonFrom)).addPoint(new GHPoint(latTo, lonTo))
            .setVehicle("car")
            .setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
            .setWeighting("fastest")
            .setAlgorithm(AlgorithmOptions.ASTAR_BI);

 req.getHints().put("pass_through", true);
 GHResponse res = hopper.route(req);
```

But I get the following error:

```
 [java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection between locations not found]
```

These are some examples of lat/long pairs I'm using:

```
 Lat1 51.519265 Long1 -0.021345 Lat2 51.502635 Long2 -0.022702
 Lat1 51.49109 Long1 -0.018716 Lat2 51.502661 Long2 -0.021596
 Lat1 51.503143 Long1 -0.008428 Lat2 51.502661 Long2 -0.021596
```

I have double checked (all) of these lat/long pairs with https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=51.499041%2C-0.020157&point=51.503083%2C-0.017676&locale=de&vehicle=car&weighting=fastest&elevation=true&layer=Lyrk and they are working.

I then searched for a solution and found [Graphhopper returns "not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432445/graphhopper-returns-not-found/26433076#26433076) which looks like an identical question so I added the following to my code:

```
hopper.setMinNetworkSize(200, 100);
```

This setting allowed graph-hopper to find a few more connections but unfortunately there are some long/lat pairs that still dont work (examples are above). What can I do to stop the RuntimeException: Connection between locations not found?

Edit:

Switching the long/lat pairs seems to be better:

```
GHRequest req2 = new GHRequest().addPoint(new GHPoint(latTo, lonTo)).addPoint(new GHPoint(latFrom, lonFrom))
```

But this provides opposite directions. How can I correct this? Does this problem occur because these are one-way streets?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.
My solution was:

```
hopper.setMinNetworkSize(200, 200);
```

When the parameter minOnewayNetworkSize is set to 200, the router does not get stuck in an (oneway) island.

See: [Graphhopper returns "not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432445/graphhopper-returns-not-found)